# Which type is str[0] in string "abc"

Tags: java, string

I have a String s="abc" in Java. What is s[0] type? Isn't it a String type?

I try to print it in Java, but it shows "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String";

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTNxm.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, post the code as code-formatted text.

Comment: `s[0]` isn't anything, because `s` isn't an array. You can only use `[]` on an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets are used to access the elements in an Array type.

String is an object, and so you can't access it's characters via [].

To access individual characters, you could either:

1. s.charAt(index)
2. char[] charArr = s.toCharArray(); and access charArr[idx]